# HTML Graph for branches

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have been looking for a JavaScript framework that can display a branch history for a custom-made version control. I have been unable to find anything myself, so I have started to make it myself, but I thought I would ask here if anyone know of a readymade framework that can already do this.

This is what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Check out http://www.graphdracula.net/

Comment: "graph" and "visualization" may be decent search terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Gitgraph.js](http://gitgraphjs.com). It's made with git in mind, but as the code examples show, you can fully control it.